# Could not find handler chain file handler-chain.xml when deploying WAR artifact from intelliJ to Tomcat 8.5.

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, intellij-idea

I'm trying to create WAR of SOAP service and deploy it to local tomcat 8.5 from IntelliJ.

The code is imported from eclipse project, where in the past I created WAR and deployed it to remote server. Now I'm using IntelliJ and trying to deploy it on local server server directly from intellij.

When deploying the code build is successful, but tomcat can't find the soap  handler-chain.xml (thats the message from tomcat logs). When I'm exporting the same code to WAR and deploy it out of intelliJ (using application manager in browser) it deploy i successfully.

After building intelliJ creates war file in out folder of project. deploying this war using browser causes "FAIL - Application at contxt path couldn't be started".

It seems to be the matter of IntelliJ. I would like to use this program (I'm working on SOAP webservice, and I'd love to deploy it and debug tomcat from it) but it doeasn't work in the way I need.

Comment: No, it's a user issue.  IntelliJ will package apps correctly when you tell it how.  Tomcat needs the file to be in the CLASSPATH.  Check the artifact that is created to see where that file is and correct it.

Comment: You were right. I need to "tell intelliJ how to package apps correctly. First thing wass the location in CLASSPATH, and the second was that I had to define the WAR structure (WEB-INF and META-INF) and all libs and classes insside them.

Comment: Well done.  Glad to hear that you sorted it out.